# Проблема с date_default_timezone_set

Tags: php

Время сервера отличается от нужного мне. Отстает от Московского на 4 часа. Использовал `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');` Но все-равно время не правильное - отстает на час. То же и с `date_default_timezone_set('MSD')` и с `date_default_timezone_set('MSK')`

Как можно однозначно верно установить время сервера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+3')
```

Показатель GMT+3 (астрономическое время меридиана) можно варьировать.

http://php.net/manual/ru/timezones.others.php

Comment: @Rikky: именно [«плюс три»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B3:00).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin прежде чем писать - протестируй, мне только что в PHP понадобилось  установить Мск время, и верным оказалось именно GMT-3...